# Django Error: No module named engine

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement this code but getting Error: No module named engine

http://github.com/robstyles/Massive-Coupon---Open-source-groupon-clone

Any thoughts?

Comment: I changed the directory to massivecoupon and ran python manage.py runserver. I got the following result:

Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0x99981ec>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserv                                                                             er.py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 2                                                                             45, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py",                                                                              line 28, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146,                                                                              in get_app_errors
    self._populate()

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61,                                                                              in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module __import__(name)
File
"/home/mycode/massivecoupon/../massivecoupon/paypalxpress/models.py", line 96 self.charged = Decimal(amount) if amount is not None else None                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax self.charged = Decimal(amount) if amount is not None else None SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: So is the error in /home/mycode/massivecoupon/../massivecoupon/paypalxpress/models.py
line 96?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have any module named "engine" on your `PYTHONPATH` anyplace. Either the installation went in the wrong location, or your Django setup was not set to include that path.

Answer (score 0):

In the github directory you point to, there's a module named "[engine](http://github.com/robstyles/Massive-Coupon---Open-source-groupon-clone/tree/master/engine/)".  The folder containing this module needs to be available on your python path.

Answer (score 0):

Check follow steps

1. is PYTHONPATH  pointed to
   massivecoupon project parent path?
2. is your proejct named massivecoupon?
   if y go 4 else go 3
3. change your project to massivecoupon
4. make sure all sub folders and parent
   folder have `__init__`.py